# Disqus for a Angular Single Page Application

Tags: html, angularjs, disqus, singlepage

I have developed a website based on Angular HTML5 Bootstrap CSS. I have embedded DISQUS for interaction and comments purpose.But , it does not work the way I want and I see the same comments in every page since mine is a single page application and I have included the DISQUS code only in home page HTML file.

However , I want unique disqus to be loaded for every async URL refresh in my angular JS single page application so that comments are unique per page.

Now I see the same comments in all the pages.Below is the disqus code that I use inside the body tag

My website

http://www.europeansaga.com/#/

```js
<script>
  /**
   *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
   *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
  /*
   var disqus_config = function () {
   this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
   this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
   };
   */
  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
   var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
   s.src = '//www-europeansaga-com.disqus.com/embed.js';
   s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
   (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
 </script>
 <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//www-europeansaga-com.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

I have used the following HTML tag where disqus loaded as a one time activity.Being a single page application the page does not refresh at all during URL change

```html
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Comment: From what I can see when I open a subpage and make a full reload the discus is the same as on the main page, so first of all you load it with the same configuration i.e. `this.page.url` and discuss can't differentiate between subpages

Comment: @maurycy Can something like this can help? https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus

Comment: @maurycy I need a solution for this to make my website more interactive I have several pages and would like to have separate interaction in each and every page